# 404 error importing css/js files into laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project done in Laravel 8 which is located inside a folder called **'MyProject'** that exists inside **Xampp's** **htdocs** folder.

In my case I'm trying to import a template made in HTML into my Laravel project.

And for that, I've already set up a route, a controller and created a view, but unfortunately I'm having problems importing the CSS and Javascript files:

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/countdown-home.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/js/countdown-widget.css') }}">
```

*(As you can see, my CSS and Javascript files are located inside the **public** folder, more specifically inside **assets**.)*

To try to solve this, I first created a new parameter inside the .ENV file (And then ran the `php artisan config:cache` command before turning on the server):

```
ASSET_URL=public
```

Unfortunately the chrome browser cannot find the files, claiming the following error message:

> GET
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyProject/public/assets/js/countdown-widget.css
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect the local address should be: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/js/countdown-widget.css` as typically the project name and public HTML folders are not identifiable to the client browser. But I'm not sure how you'd go about changing these values

Comment: The public folder should be the root of your domain. Its best to create a domain for your app in your hosts file, and point it to the Laravel public folder. Note that using XAMPP is not ideal for laravel apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

After a few failed attempts, I decided to do something different.

I removed the laravel project folder *('MyProject')* from inside htdocs and placed it on my *desktop*, and from there I ran `php artisan serve`.

And magically everything worked as expected, so I suppose laravel was having trouble finding the css files while the project was located inside the htdocs folder.